# Google Apps Script that aligns all cells in all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

At the moment, I have to go through every sheet and use this macro to align it vertically and horizontally. Is there a way of tweaking this script to align all sheets instead of having to do each one manually?

```
function Alignment() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setHorizontalAlignment('center')
  .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all sheets and iterate over each sheet:

```
function Alignment() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setHorizontalAlignment('center')
  .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  });
};
```

If you want to get more performance but you won't be able to see the changes as they are hapenning in the sheets, then try this:

```
function Alignment() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{
  let rg=sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  rg.setHorizontalAlignment('center')
  .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  });
};
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
However, I realised that this is a bad idea for a spreadsheet that had 58 sheets in it.... lol. Although it causes a significant amount of lag, it definitely works!

Comment: Try not doing it for max rows instead just do it for the data range

Comment: @Nitrolysis glad it worked for you. Consider my updated answer as per Cooper suggestion. It should be way faster and more efficient. I think it will be more suitable for you. If it does not work I apologise in advance.

Comment: Wow this is unbelievably satisfying to watch; and yeah like you said, it is a lot better. 
Not as quick though because it goes through each one instead of doing it all at once and I have over 50 sheets, so it does take a while. But thank you very much!

Comment: @Nitrolysis check also my second code, but I think that's the maximum performance you can get.

Comment: @Marios I don't think the second code is any faster, but it is much better! Because it allows me to carry on doing what I want to do instead of seeing every sheet that it's alligning and being unable to do anything until it's done. Thanks again!